# Two similar pose has a big relative euler angle

Tags: eigen, eigen3, euler-angles

There are two similar poses represented by Euler angle:

```
s_euler_angle_o1:
0.000549608
    -3.1334
    1.23193
s_euler_angle_o2:
0.0222646
 -3.10948
  1.31032
```

But the relative Euler angle computed by Eigen is

```
o1_euler_angle_o2:
 3.11182
-3.12907
-3.06258
```

The Euler convention is ZYX.
The code I compute the o1_euler_angle_o2 is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "sophus/se3.h"
#include "sophus/so3.h"
#include <Eigen/Core>
Sophus::SE3 EulerTranslatetoSE3(Eigen::Vector3d euler_angle, Eigen::Vector3d translate){
        Eigen::Matrix3d o1_R_on = (Eigen::AngleAxisd(euler_angle[0],Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ())*Eigen::AngleAxisd(euler_angle[1],Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())*Eigen::AngleAxisd(euler_angle[2],Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX())).matrix();
        Sophus::SE3 o1_T_on_sop(o1_R_on,translate);
        return o1_T_on_sop;

    }
int main() {
    Eigen::Vector3d s_euler_angle_o1 = Eigen::Vector3d(0.000549608,-3.1334,1.23193);
    Eigen::Vector3d s_euler_angle_o2 = Eigen::Vector3d(0.0222646,-3.10948,1.31032);
    Eigen::Vector3d s_t_o1 = Eigen::Vector3d(0.0148442,0.0453362,0.342611);
    Eigen::Vector3d s_t_o2 = Eigen::Vector3d(0.0213847,0.0488918,0.341841);

    Sophus::SE3 s_T_o1 = EulerTranslatetoSE3(s_euler_angle_o1,s_t_o1);
    Sophus::SE3 s_T_o2 = EulerTranslatetoSE3(s_euler_angle_o2,s_t_o2);
    Sophus::SE3 o1_T_o2 = s_T_o1.inverse() * s_T_o2;
    Eigen::Matrix3d o1_R_o2 = o1_T_o2.rotation_matrix();
    Eigen::Vector3d o1_euler_angle_o2 = o1_R_o2.eulerAngles(2,1,0);
    std::cout<<"o1_euler_angle_o2:\n"<<o1_euler_angle_o2<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakelist.txt is below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#sophus
find_package(Sophus REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Sophus_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test main.cpp)
# Eigen
include_directories("/usr/include/eigen3" )
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE
        ${DEPENDENCIES}
        ${Sophus_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

I use Euler angle since the Euler angle is three-dimension. It is easier to implement in genetic algorithm.

Is this relative pose the only result? If not, is there a result can reflect the small relative pose using Euler angle?

Comment: What Euler convention do you use? How do you calculate `o1_euler_angle_o2`? (--> Provide a [mre]!) Also, why do you use Euler angles at all?

Comment: @chtz I'm sorry, I thought this was a mathematical problem before. I have added the detail now.

Comment: Can you produce an example which compiles by just copy+pasting it? Do you need the `Sophus` stuff to reproduce the problem? Also (repeating myself): Why do you need Euler angles?

Comment: @chtz I'm sorry. I  add the source code just now. Yes, I need `Sophus`. I use Euler angle since the Euler angle is three-dimension. It is easier to implement in genetic algorithm.

Comment: It's been a while that I looked at Sophus, but shouldn't one of its base functionality be to provide SO3-logarithm and exponential (mapping SO3 to and from R^3)? (Or SE3-log/exp mapping SE3 to/from R^6)

Comment: @chtz Yes, the Sophus is major in Lie algebra, but this is not the key point, the Sophus can also compute the Lie group multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is entirely valid. But by the [documentation of `.eulerAngles()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#ga17994d2e81b723295f5bc3b1f862ed3b) the range of returned angles is `[0:pi]x[-pi:pi]x[-pi:pi]`. In your case this is unfortunate, since there would be a smaller representation which however requires a negative value for the first angle.

If you really need Euler-Angles, you can try out the [unsupported Euler-Angles module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__EulerAngles__Module.html) of Eigen, which allows much more configuration of the output.

But if you just need a good SO3->R^3 mapping I strongly suggest using the logarithmic map associated with the Lie-group (that is what `Sophus::SO3::log` should be calculating). Also I'll shamelessly plug a paper on that topic: "Integrating Generic Sensor Fusion Algorithms with Sound State Representations through Encapsulation of Manifolds" (shouldn't be hard to find online).